# How can I remove space from assertion

Tags: java, selenium, assertion

How can I remove space from .size.

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected [ 9] but found [9]

```
List<WebElement> editicons = 
   driver.findElements(By.xpath("//i[@class='material-icons']"));
        for (int j = 1; j <= editicons.size(); j++) {
            editicons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//i[@class='material-icons']"));
            String porfolioName = driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//mat-table//mat-row)[" + j + "]//mat-cell[2]"))
                    .getText(); 
            Thread.sleep(1000); 
            Reporter.log("Successfully rendered  no " + porfolioName);
            Add_Log.info("Successfully rendered no " + porfolioName);   
        }   
        String savecount = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mat-paginator-range-label']")).getText();
        String[] trimmedText = savecount.split("of");   
        Reporter.log("Total number of Approve: " + trimmedText[1]);
        Add_Log.info("Total number of Approve: " + trimmedText[1]);
    Assert.assertEquals(editicons.size(), trimmedText[1]);
}
```

Comment: `editicons.size()` should return an `int` while `trimmedText[1]` would be a `String`. Even with autoboxing those would never be equal.

Comment: In addition to Thomas' comment, your split parameter should probably be " of " or "of " and not "of"

Answer (score 2):

Convert `String` to `Integer` using static method `parseInt` of Integer class (A wrapper class of int data type). To get rid of leading and trailing spaces we can use `String` class `trim` method.

```
Assert.assertEquals(editicons.size(), Integer.parseInt(trimmedText[1].trim));
```